# How to communicate with activity after long task because activity was destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have created simple application with login feature. I have created separate task for do the login into server called `LoginTask` and a listener class called `LoginListener`.

```
public interface LoginListener {
    public void onLoginComplete();
    public void onLoginFailure(String msg);
}

public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
    private final LoginListener listener;
    private final Context c;
    private String msg;

    public LoginTask(final Context c, final LoginListener listener) {
        this.c = c;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        // loging in to server
        //return true if success
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean status) {
        if(!status){
            if(listener != null) listener.onLoginFailure(msg);
                return;
        }       

        // the problem is here, listener is null, because activity/fragment destroyed
        if(listener != null) listener.onLoginComplete();
    }
}
```

I executed `LoginTask` from `LoginFragment`. The `LoginFragment` implements `LoginListener`.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements LoginListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_login, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        doInitView();
    };

    private void doInitView(){
        Button loginButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        Button regButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toreg_btn);

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        regButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    private void doLogin(){
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        EditText emailText = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        EditText pwdText = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.login_pwd);

        String email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
        String pwd = pwdText.getText().toString().trim();

        if(StringUtil.isAnyNull(email, pwd)){
            Popup.showMsg(getActivity(), "Silahkan lengkapi data", Popup.SHORT);
            return;
        }

        savedEmail = email;
        savedPwd = pwd;
        String url = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.url_login);
        Popup.showLoading(getActivity(), "Login", "Please wait...");
        LoginTask task = new LoginTask(getActivity(), this);
        task.execute(url, email, pwd);
    }

    private final class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.login_btn:
                doLogin();
                break;
            case R.id.toreg_btn:
                doToRegister();
                break;
            case R.id.demo_btn:
                doDemo();
                break;
            }
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginComplete() {
        // getActivity() is null
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).gotoMain();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailure(String msg) {

    }    
}
```

Because of the login task takes time, sometime the device light turn off before the task was finished so activity was destroyed. This caused the task failed to call the listener(fragment). How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncTask` should be used for tasks that take a bit longer and return a result into the current activity. However it's not intended for really long running tasks or for those cases where you want to evaluate its results even if the activity has been destroyed.

You might consider using a `Service` here. In any case you shouldn't do updates in `onPostExecute()` anymore cause the activity context might be gone (see *Doctoror Drive*'s post).

Having that service in place, you can either send an `Intent` or a `Broadcast` event to the system. Then do the further processing in that intent activity / broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the asynctask in onDestroy() of your LoginActivity.

Override onCancelled() of the asynctask. When the activity is destroyed, a call to onCancelled() will be made instead of onPostExecute()

Here you can avoid a call back to the LoginActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Service` or `IntentService`. because `AsyncTask` does not record any variables or context of `Activity`. When you finish login task launch `PendingIntent` or `startActivity(intent)`. This can be best practice of Android. This way you never get exception.

Answer (score 0):

In onLoginComplete and onLoginFailure check if the fragment is still attached to the activity. If not, do nothing.

```
@Override
public void onLoginComplete() {

    if (isAdded() && !isRemoving() && !isDetached()) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).gotoMain();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I need to call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).gotoMain();`, how to do that?

Comment: the problem arise when the activity was destroyed, how to call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).gotoMain();` ?

Comment: If the Activity is destroyed you can't reference it from fragment anymore since it is detached, and probably the new fragment instance will be created and the current will be lost.  You need to change your behaviour. You can cancel login if Activity is destroyed as suggested in Arun's answer.